# Set default date in Mongoose document to now + [some increment]

Tags: mongodb, mongoose

Looking at setting a default timestamp for a document to now + 1 minute/hour/day. How would I go about modifying this to do so:

```
date: { type: Date, default: Date.now }
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can define a **[default](http://mongoosejs.com/docs/2.8.x/docs/defaults.html)** with a function:

```
var minuteFromNow = function(){
    var timeObject = new Date();
    timeObject.setTime(timeObject.getTime() + 1000 * 60);
    return timeObject;
};

new Schema({
    date: { type: Date, default: minuteFromNow }
})
```

---

-- **EDIT** --

You can also use the **[momentjs](http://momentjs.com/)** library which has got some fantastic methods on the date object, in particular the [**`add()`**](http://momentjs.com/docs/#/manipulating/add/) function for your use case:

```
var moment = require('moment');
var hourFromNow = function(){
    return moment().add(1, 'hour');
};

new Schema({
    date: { type: Date, default: hourFromNow }
})


/* OR */
new Schema({
    date: { type: Date, default: function(){return moment().add(1, 'hour');} }
})
```

Comment: when I am doing `default: hourFromNow`, then my IDE which is Webstorm is blacking out word `default`, do you have any idea why is it happening, is this some kind of an error?