# Storing time using default in mongoose schema , saves the same time again and again

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose, mongoose-schema

I have a mongoose schema which includes:

```
dateTime: {
    type: Date,
    default: moment().tz("Asia/Karachi").format(),
},
```

But when I am saving records in MongoDB its storing the same time again and again.

Record One saved:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/42bjM.png)

Record Two saved:

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yNjFb.png)

Comment: This may help you https://stackoverflow.com/a/30525690/4156021

Comment: Thanks @AnkurR , but could you explain the problem , why this issue arises.

Comment: As per your code it takes only value of the code `moment().tz("Asia/Karachi").format()` while first schema was created. And if you create the call back function then it will call it everytime. I hope this helps

Comment: @AnkurR thanks for clarifying.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

By specifing a `default` value this exact value will be used for all the records. You probably want to define a `default` function instead:

```
dateTime: {
    type: Date,
    default: () => moment().tz("Asia/Karachi").format()
},
```